# Pass slug and context to render page?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm displaying an Entry using DetailView and also have a comment form on the same page.

The commment form works fine for submissions but it doesn't display validation errors.

I can't figure out how to pass *both* the **slug** (required for the DetailView) *AND* the **form** (which contains the validation errors).

I'm not trying to display the slug in my html template -- I need the slug to retrieve the Entry's detailview.

Url:

```
...
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', EntryDetailView.as_view(), name='entry_detail'),
...
```

View:

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = "entry_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['comments'] =  [(comment, comment.get_children_count()) for comment in EntryComment.get_tree()]

        entry_comment_form = EntryCommentForm()
        context['entry_comment_form'] = entry_comment_form

        return context

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        # If the user created the entry:
        try: return Entry.objects.get(Q(slug=self.kwargs['slug']), author=self.request.user.id)
        except: pass

        # If the user received the entry:
        try: return Entry.objects.get(Q(slug=self.kwargs['slug']), recipients=self.request.user)
        except: pass

        # Otherwise, bye-bye.
        raise Http404

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        entry_comment_form = EntryCommentForm(request.POST)

        if entry_comment_form.is_valid():
            entry_comment_form.add_method(
                author=entry_comment_form.cleaned_data['author'],
                body=entry_comment_form.cleaned_data['body'],
                date_created=datetime.datetime.now()
            )

            success(request, 'Success')
            slug = self.kwargs['slug']

            # Proper? It works.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('entry_detail', subdomain='blog', kwargs={'slug':slug}))

        else:
            error(request, 'Error')
            slug = self.kwargs['slug']

            # Here's where I need to render the same Entry but include the form context so I can display the validation errors.
            return render(
                request,
                reverse('entry_detail', kwargs={'slug':slug}), 
                {'entry_comment_form':entry_comment_form}
            )
```

Seems like it's just a rookie mistake somewhere due to my lack of python/django foo.

The end goal is to display the same DetailView page (is there a way to do this without passing the slug to the url?) and include the form in context so I can display comment form validation errors.

Searched around, couldn't find any relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

What if you refactor it to use one of the customtags that come with the commenting module?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/comments/#quickly-rendering-the-comment-form

Can you just use the `get_comment_form` tag with `object` to avoid passing the form around?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying makes no sense. You are passing the result of `reverse` - ie a URL - as the *template* in a call to the `render` function. Why are you doing that?

In order to actually help you, though, we'd need to know what you are actually doing. Where is this strange code? Is it in a view function, a class-based view method, a template tag, or somewhere else?

**Edit after full code posted**

There are several things wrong with that view code (blank `excepts` that just do `pass`?), but I will concentrate on the issue at hand. You seem to be making this much harder than it needs to be: if you want to pass both the form and the slug/URL to the template, you just put them in the template context, and pass the context to `render` as normal. There's nothing out of the ordinary or complicated here at all.

```
return render(
    request,
    self.template_name,
    {'entry_comment_form':entry_comment_form, 'slug': slug}
)
```

Note that it's probably best to pass the `slug` in the context and use the `url` tag in the template:

```
{% url 'entry_detail' slug=slug %}
```

Comment: But that has nothing to do with `render`. That's for rendering a template, hence the name. Why are you calling render at all?

Comment: You're still not explaining what you're hoping to **do** with those things, though. And you need to explain properly where this code lives, in context: ie post the **actual** view showing where you call it and what you're hoping to do with the response.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not prepared to help you further unless you show the actual code that's using this function, and the full code of the function (not an invalid snippet as you have posted now).